# csv file giving showing wrong value

Tags: java, csv

I am using this code for encoding Japanese character in csv file:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(path + ".csv","UTF8");
```

But when my csv is downloaded in one column i am getting value like this:

```
ä¸¸å…¨æ˜­å’Œé‹è¼¸ .
```

Please help me how to correct this.

Comment: How/when are you getting this value? When you open it in your Text Editor? In Excel? You need to tell the application that reads the CSV that you are using UTF-8, as well.

Comment: When i opened in Excel

Comment: I don't fully unterstand. Did you checked the written CSV-file in some editor if the characters are written correctly? You say your csv is downloaded. By what? What does column means? Is the font you use or the column-class (or whatever that is) capable of showing japanese characters?

Comment: When i downloaded my file, in excel the value is showing like this: ä¸¸å…¨æ˜­å’Œé‹è¼¸ .

Comment: If you print normal ASCII text, does that work?

Comment: Yes............